# Permissions to view video file without being able to copy

Tags: permissions, files

Is there any way in which I could allow a user to access/view a video without allowing them to be able to move or copy it. I am asking because at college there is a folder with lots of videos on them however only teachers are able to access them because otherwise students would make lots of copies of them and I was wondering if it would be possible to allow the students to have access to the videos so they could watch them without being able to copy them.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Could you please explain how your question relates to Ubuntu? Otherwise it’s off topic on Ask**Ubuntu**. Instead your question may fit on [Unix.SE] or more generally [SU].

Comment: Short answer: No. Viewing and copying are both read operations and the computer cannot distinguish between different purposes of an operation. If you have permission to read something you can do both; otherwise you can do neither.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying I asked on askubuntu because I am using ubuntu 17.04

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer:** You can prevent users from moving the file, however you can't prevent them from copying the file while they're able to read (watch) it.

---

When you are moving a file, simply you are creating a new hard link to that data in another directory and at the same time you are removing its entry from its current directory.

So to prevent moving a file, you should remove the write access of others from its parent directory:

```
chmod 775 Directory
```

Now others can read (watch) the file however they can't move it. do not forget that the file itself should have a permission similar to this:

```
chmod 664 File
```

so others can't mess around its content.

For making a copy of a specific file, you just need to be able of read it, when you can read something you can make a copy of it.

Comment: To expand on the last part, preventing anyone from making a copy of a file that they can read is impossible in both principle and practice.